# What is Amazon's S3 template and can it be exploited?

Tags: vpn, amazon

I'm trying to make a vpn on CloudFormation following this [guide](https://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2015/how-to-setup-your-own-private-secure-free-vpn-on-the-amazon-aws-cloud-in-10-minutes/). It's telling me to use the template given [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/webdigi/VPN/Unified-Cloud-Formation.json). I'm not familar with what an S3 template does and whether if I should trust this guide or not. It seems a bit sketchy to me.

Comment: the template is just a settings file